# pass parents function arguments in a nested function?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I am having a problem with arguments object in a nested function, seems like arguments.length is taken from parent function while arguments[0] is taken from nested function...   anybody can explain why this is happening ?and show me the most effective way to pass parent foo's arguments to bar?

```
$.fn.foo = function(color1, color2, time ){
    return this.each(function bar(){

        for(var i = 0;i < (arguments.length - 1);i++){
            alert(arguments.length); //this is taken from foo function and returns 2   
        alert(arguments[i]); //this is taken from  bar 

        }
    });
    };
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you pass a named function `bar` into the each function, instead of just an anonymous one?

Comment: @Zirak, presumably to make the question clear and to be able to refer to the function by its name. It's actually a great idea for that reason!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution: Get a local reference to `arguments`.

```
$.fn.foo = function(color1, color2, time ){
    var args = arguments; // Create a private reference
    return this.each(function bar(){
        alert(args.length); //Use private reference
    });
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`arguments` will always (unless changed) have the scope of the currently executing function, which in your case is `bar`.

Read the jquery `.each` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/), the function "prototype" is as follows:

`.each( function(index, Element) )`

So of course `arguments.length` will return 2. Whether or not you have named variables to catch those 2 sent arguments is another story, but the arguments object will have length 2 if the function was called with 2 arguments.